# Orion context broker global instance token

Tags: fiware-orion

I want to publish some data on the Orion context broker global instance and I have requested a token as referred at [Quick start guide](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick_start_guide/index.html). When I continue coding (java client) next day I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509)
at publishers.fiware.OrionClient.getEntities(OrionClient.java:23)
at FiwareTest.main(FiwareTest.java:11)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:792)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:789)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:253)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
... 6 more
```

So I requested a new token and worked again.

A token generated that way has an expiration time? How much?

Do I have a way to get a non expiring token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with OpenStack Keystone default configuration, tokens expires after 1 hour:

http://docs.openstack.org/juno/config-reference/content/section_keystone.conf.html

```
# Amount of time a token should remain valid (in seconds).
# (integer value)
#expiration=3600
```

You can renew it by getting another one:

http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/index.html?expanded=#token-authentication-with-unscoped-authorization

```
POST /v3/auth/tokens HTTP/1.1
Host: test.ttcloud.net:5001
Content-Type: application/json
X-Auth-Token: {{user-token}}
{
 "auth": {
    "identity": {
        "methods": [
            "token"
        ],
        "token": {
            "id": "{{user-token}}"
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I had success renewing but only after adding username and password to payload: